# how can i create media query free fluid width to INCREASE as the screen width decreases?

Tags: css

Is there a way to write a css fluid width without using media queries to 
increase as the screen width descreases?

use case: to position element in the centre of a wide screen >= 1200px at 50% width of its container element, increasing to 100% when the screen width <= 600px. In between I need width to adjust fluidly between the two limits.

<= 600px
width:100%;

> = 1200px
>   width:50%;

thanks.

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use media queries?

you could use JS to toggle classed for below 600px and above 1200px respectively... and % or vw units for the in between

Comment: _“In between I need width to adjust fluidly between the two limits”_ - I guess that should be achievable using `calc()`, if you can figure out the right “formula”.

Comment: i can use media queries this is an exercise in calc(). I specifically dont want to do this with media queries, but my algebra for linear inverse formulas is a little rusty.

Answer (score -2):

Use the max-width property:

```
Max-width:100%;
```